# How to use the Postgres FORMAT function along with LIKE patterns that contain %?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I am trying to create a formatted string for a `WHERE` clause.
I need to insert `LIKE` syntax inside the `FORMAT()` function.

Here is my SQL code snippet:

```
FORMAT(' AND student_name LIKE  %%L% ', CAST(jsnData->>'term' AS VARCHAR) );
```

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) says,

> In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special sequence `%%` may be used to output a literal `%` character.

So your expression should be

```
format($$ AND student_name LIKE  '%%' || %L || '%%' $$, jsnData->>'term')
```

(The cast is unnecessary.)

Comment: `%%%L%%` will put single quotes in the wrong places, like `%'replacement-text'%`. Better use `''%%%s%%''` to get `'%replacement-text%'`. SQLi prone.